# Getting NoClassDefFoundError with Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) on Nexus 4

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have the gcm.jar in my classpath, so eclipse compiles the project but it fails on my Nexus 4 device with

```
02-24 11:52:12.645: E/AndroidRuntime(30240): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 11:52:12.645: E/AndroidRuntime(30240): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar
02-24 11:52:12.645: E/AndroidRuntime(30240):    at com.foo.closethedoor.CloseTheDoorActivity.onCreate(CloseTheDoorActivity.java:77)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have the gcm.jar in my classpath

It needs to be in your project's `libs/` directory. Do not just manipulate the Eclipse build path manually -- that will allow you *compile* against the JAR but does not *ship* the JAR with your APK. Putting the JAR in `libs/` does both.

Comment: That did it. Had no idea libs was a special folder. This is my first non maven project. Thanks

Comment: you have to download the google play service and add the jar into your project

Answer (score 1):

NoClassDefFoundError means the Application is unable to find the location of the file inside the Application's folder. 
It is advised to keep all the library files and jar files in 'libs' folder of the Project.Try doing so.It will resolve the issue.
If not, try building the code again before pushing it onto the device.